# WebView in background won't load webpages

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-webview

I want my app to navigate every five minutes to a certain webpage while the display is off. Therefore i created an AlarmReceiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class BackgroundAlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        MainActivity.Current.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            FMain.WV.LoadUrl("http://127.0.0.1/");
        });
    }
}
```

WV is attached to the layout of the fragment 'FMain' and a static parameter of it.

This works fine while the screen is on, but when I turn my screen off and turn it on a few minutes later, most of the times I get to see "Webpage not available, ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" (but sometimes it loads even while the screen is of).

The webview has DomStorage and JavaScript enabled and a standard WebViewClient:

```
public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
     public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
     {
          view.LoadUrl(request.Url.ToString());
          return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens, because android system kills your web view. Do you really need to render some page every 5 minutes in background, or you just want to send request?

Comment: @91378246 it's very bad for battery life.

Comment: @91378246 Why do you need to load it?